# Image Uploaded To Customizer Not Displaying

Tags: theme-customizer

I have added a section in my customizer to upload a background image for my main site.  I am calling it here:

```
.header_wrapper{
background:url('<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'header_image_uploaded', 'http://www.unitedwayofmilford.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Canva-Lending-a-helping-hand..jpg' ); ?>') no-repeat center center fixed;
```

It is not showing up.

Here is the code for my customizer functions

```
function uwm_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'header_image' , array(
'default'   => 'http://www.unitedwayofmilford.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Canva-Lending-a-helping-hand.jpg',) );

$wp_customize->add_section( 'main_header_image' , array(
'title'      => __( 'Choose Your Main Image', 'uwm' ),) );

$wp_customize->add_control( 
new WP_Customize_Upload_Control( 
$wp_customize, 
'header_image_uploaded', 
array(
    'label'      => __( 'Main Image Upload', 'uwm' ),
    'section'    => 'main_header_image',
    'settings'   => 'header_image',) ) );
}add_action( 'customize_register', 'uwm_customize_register' );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the field will be the ID of the uploaded attachment. Not an image URL. You will need to use `wp_get_attachment_image_url()` to get the URL.

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_theme_mod( 'header_image_uploaded' ), 'full' );
```